# How to increase drop area of connected sortable list, but still increase list height from first item

Tags: jquery

In jquery, I have two connected sortable lists stacked on top of eachother so that visually they appear to be one big list. The only problem is, since I need a minimum height on the top list to drop in items even when it's empty, moving an item from the bottom list into the empty top list causes the appearance of the combined lists suddenly "moving up" since the item fills the currently empty space of the ul, rather than expanding to under it.

I need a way to drop items into the list when it's empty, while still expanding the list area on the first item dropped in, so it doesn't cause this effect.

I tried using an invisible list item, but I don't want the user to be able to place other items above it. I'm not sure how to prevent this from happening.

```
min-height: 30px;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yLcpr0h2/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution; I was overthinking it. Just add padding top of the first list instead of using min-height:

```
padding-top: 30px;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5p0adsf8/